# How to delete a specific set of ??.png files in a directory?

Tags: files, rm

I accidentally extracted an archive containing about a hundred files

```
??.png
```

where `?` is normal ASCII character `a` - `z`. Meaning there are two characters and it's PNG pictures.

I'd rather learn how to do this in CLI, Bash to be specific, rather than trying to do this in GUI.

**EIDT1:**

Note that I can't simply use

```
rm ??.png
```

because there are other files numbered like 01.png etc which I want to keep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very easy and intuitive:

```
rm [a-z][a-z].png
```

To check if the filenames to delete are correct, print them using:

```
echo [a-z][a-z].png
```

Comment: I missed the hint `a` - `z` only. I think, `[a-z][a-z].png` should work then

Comment: No problem. If there are no other files (as `w3.png` for example), both should work. Just check first :)

Comment: To give a broader explanation of the topic, what you were asking about (matching specific characters, groups of characters, etc.) falls under [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)